# A div inside of a mat-dialog has to move over when opening the dialog, rather than being in the right place (already using position: absolute)

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, mat-dialog

Inside an application I am developing, I have an Angular Material dialog that contains a mat-selection-list of companies and a mat-list of alphabetical characters that can be clicked on to jump to different alphabetical headers. My issue is that my mat-list containing my alphabet (the right hand side of the dialog) has to "pop" into place every time the dialog is launched, rather than being where it is supposed to be initially. This looks a bit sloppy/jumpy, and I was wondering if there was any way I could get it to be in the proper location.

Here is a gif that showcases the issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZe7w.jpg

Here is my current code:

```
// Opening the dialog
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CompanySelectionDialog, {
  width: '90vw',
  panelClass: 'companySelectionPanel', 
  data: {companies: this.companies},
  disableClose: true
});
```

And the HTML for the actual dialog content:

```
<!-- Dialog Page HTML -->
<mat-dialog-content>
  <div *ngFor="let companies of this.companiesSortedByLetter" style="width: 95%">
    <mat-toolbar [id]="companies.letter">
      <span>{{ companies.letter.toUpperCase() }}</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-selection-list #companies [multiple]="false" [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany">
      <mat-list-option ngDefaultControl *ngFor="let sortedCompany of companies.companies" [value]="sortedCompany" mat-dialog-close (click)="onSelect(selectedCompany[0])">
        {{ sortedCompany.Description + ' ' + sortedCompany.ID }}
      </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
  </div>
  <div style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 83.5%; bottom: 50%; top: 20%; right: 0%; z-index: 100;">
    <mat-list>
      <mat-list-item class="alphaList" ontouchmove="console.log('moved')" matRipple
        *ngFor="let letter of this.companiesSortedByLetter"
        (click)="scrollToLetter(letter.letter)">{{ letter.letter.toUpperCase() }}
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
  </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

And the style rules in my global.scss for the panel:

```
.companySelectionPanel {
  .alphaList {
    @media screen and (max-height: 1024px) {
      height: 30px !important
    }

    @media screen and (min-height: 1366px) {
      height: 38px !important
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any insight anyone could give on this.

Comment: Feels like an update rate issue; the dialog is busy animating growing into place, and the components are initialising and rendering in the middle of that, causing them to reflow once the animation is over. Someone may have a better/proper solution, but possibly you could delay it showing and/or give it an animation for loading in over the same span so that it isn't so jarring?

Comment: @Krenom I was thinking something along those lines. It wouldn't be the most preferred way, but it may be the only way due to the way the dialog works.